# How to retrieve the language of the current user with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm looking for javascript code that will return the language selected by the current logged in crm user. Is there another method than reading the language setting from the used internet browser.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the user's locale ID through the function `Xrm.Page.context.getUserLcid();`

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664) a list of the possible LCIDs

Comment: Simple question, simple answer. PERFECT! Thank you!